fail to activate conda env after restarting session in colab
after I restart the colab session, I can no longer activate my conda environment:
$!conda activate svgrender 
CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'

and seems I am not in my base environment either:
$!conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /usr/local
svgrender                /usr/local/envs/svgrender

Wondering how should I fix it? Thanks!
I tried sth like
!conda init bash

But they all don't work.
